# Is it possible to remove cherrypicked commits of an unmerged branch from PR?

Tags: git, github

I have an old branch `old_main --> branch A commits` which is X commits behind main and not merged yet.

I have a new branch `updated_main --> branch B commits`. I need to use branch A commits in this branch B, so I rebased. Now I have something like `updated_main --> branch A commits --> branch B commits`.

When I create a PR for branch B, the commit history includes the commits from branch A, which should not be reviewed in this PR.

Is it possible to remove `branch A commits` from the history while still using the changes?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Suppose you could though- if B depends on A and you only merged in B, then wouldn't B be broken without A getting merged in also? Sounds like you should just do a PR for A first, and then do your PR for B.

Comment: @TTT You're right, A needs to be merged first then B. I'm just waiting for my PR A to get reviewed and merged and I thought I'd work on PR B in the meantime. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: Ah, I see your goal now. I added an answer with a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible. If you only want to see the changes specific to your PR, you'll have to wait for Branch A's PR to complete before you'll be able to isolate only Branch B's commits in a PR.

However, that doesn't mean you can't start the review process on Branch B. You could still create the PR and put a comment in asking the reviewers to review specific commits in Branch B rather than all the files. That way you can begin the review process, especially if you anticipate suggested changes. Once Branch A's PR is completed, if the commit IDs didn't change, those commits should fall out of Branch B's PR. If the commit IDs did change, simply rebase B onto the updated `main` once more and then you can finalize Branch B's PR.